# What is the meaning of against in this context?

Tags: american-english, british-english

It's two reasons for teenagers to wear mask, One is to stop them infecting other people but also there is one element of protection against other kids who are also chattering away as they go along that crowded corridor.

Source of info: https://youtu.be/KD44ynY6Wts?t=207

Can you explain why they use against here? wearing the mask is a protection of element that support others. So why against?

Comment: Your clip only starts at the end of the sentence, but "There are two reasons for teenagers to wear masks" would seem more likely. Why _against_? Because you protect yourself _against_ something that could harm you - here, catching the virus from other children..

Answer (score 2):

*Protect* implies that there is a threat of some kind. We use *from* or *against* to express what that threat is.

The threat is really Covid, or infection by Covid:

> The mask protects us against infection/Covid.

But by [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) we can also refer to the source of the infection as the threat:

> The mask protects us against people with Covid.

and specifically

> The mask protects us against children who are chattering, and therefore, if infected, breathing out the virus.

By the way *It's for two reasons for ...* is not idiomatic English. We can say *It's for two reasons.* as the reply to a question, but if we are going to qualify it with a purpose (*for students to wear masks*), only *There are two reasons* is idiomatc.

Comment: Colin, another upvote. it could be from, too.